# The use of か [ka]

Tags: particle-か

So I've been wondering around, thinking about if it would be wrong to use the character か after the shortened phrase 元気。That is 元気 as in [ お元気ですか？]. Would it still mean the same  if you did it like this [元気か] or would that be grammatically incorrect?
The point is to make certain to the person talking to that it is a question and that you are not just saying "fine".

Comment: Is it grammatical? Yes. Is it appropriate? That's another question... Depends on who you're speaking to. You probably don't want to "mouth off" this way to someone you should respect ;)

Comment: I would think of か used this way as similar to finishing a question with “huh?” or “or what?” In English, if that helps you understand the tone.

Answer (score 3):

"元気か?" is grammatical, but it tends to sound fairly blunt and/or haughty. In fiction, an old man, a stereotyped strict father or a yakuza boss may say this. Usually "元気?" *with a rising intonation* is used in friendly and casual conversations.

If such a question is not directly cast to a person, "noun/na-adj + か" may be more acceptable. People often say "マジか?" or "アホか?" when they saw something unbelievable, although these still sound a little rough.